# Location of variables in C

Tags: c, operating-system, osdev

I'm trying to understand how C allocates memory to global variables.

I'm working on a simple Kernel. So far it can't do much more than print to screen and enable interrupts. I'm now working on a basic physical memory manager.

My memory manager is a bitmap that sets a 1 or 0 if memory is allocated or available. I need to add the memory that my Kernel is using to the bitmap as 'allocated', so nothing overwrites it.

I can easily find out the start of the Kernel, as it's statically loaded to 0x100000. Figuring out the length shouldn't be too difficult either. The part I'm not sure about is where global variables are put in memory?

Let's say my Kernel is 12K, I can then allocate these 3x 4K blocks of memory to it for protection. Do I need to allocate more to cover the variables it uses? Or are the variables part of that 12K?

Thank you for your help, I hope I am making enough sense.

Comment: If you didn't find that site yet, I'd like to recommend http://wiki.osdev.org/ and http://forum.osdev.org/.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/14268

your globals mostly are in the BSS

Comment: Thank you. So from what I understand, the Kernel space in memory is made up of the Kernel code (data/text segment), the initialised data, uninitialised data (bss), and the heap/stack. So, I need to protect everything from the start of the Kernel code to the start of the Stack. Have I understood correctly?

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer says, most variables are stored in the .bss section but they can also be stored in the .data or .rodata section depending on if you defined the global variables as static or const. After compiling you can use readelf -S kernel.bin to see exactly how much space each section will utilize. For the .bss section the memory is only occupied when the binary is loaded in memory and does not take any space on disk. This means that your compiled kernel binary will be smaller than the actual size it will later use when brought into memory (by grub usually).

A simple way to figure out exactly how much data your kernel will use besides using readelf is to place the .bss section inside the .data section within your linker script. The size of the kernel binary will then be the same size both on disk as in memory (or actually it will be a bit smaller in memory since not all sections are copied by grub) but then at least you know the minimum amount of memory you need to allocate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a custom linker script (assuming you use `gcc`): it makes the layout of kernel sections explicit and customizable (to read more about linker scripts, read `info ld`). You can see an example of my OS's linker script [here](https://github.com/EarlGray/COSEC/blob/master/vmcosec.lds.S).

To see the default linker script use `-v`/`--verbose` option of `ld`.

Mostly global variables are located in `.data.*` and `.rodata.*` sections, variables initialized with 0 go in `.bss`.